# Example of module on dimension $d$ with trivial local cohomology $H^d_I(M)$.

Tags: commutative-algebra, local-cohomology

Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring, $I$ is an ideal. Are there examples of an $R$-module $M$ such that local cohomology $H^d_I(M)=0$, where $d=\dim M$.

It is well-known that there are no such examples over local Noetherian rings. It is also not hard to show that $H^i_I(M)=0$ for $i>d$ for any Noetherian ring.

Comment: Let $R= k[x,y]$, $I=(x)$, and $M=R$. Then $\dim(M) = 2$ but $H^2_I(R) = 0$.

Comment: From your second sentence, I'm wondering if what you actually want is an example of a module $M$ such that $H^d_{\mathfrak{m}}(M) = 0$, where $\mathfrak{m}$ is the maximal (or maximal homogeneous) ideal of $R$.

Comment: Thank for this example and yes, it would be nice to have an example with maximal ideal of $R$.